# figcaption vertical height of figure?

Tags: html, css

I have a `figure` tag, within which I have an `img` and `figcaption`.

I am trying to get the width of the `figcaption` to match the height of the `figure` (which is variable based on window size, in the was you would perhaps use `vh` to match the browser height. The reason for this is that I am rotating the `figcaption` 90degrees, and wish to have the `figcaption` text centred to the height of the figure.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j4fqanfn/)

**HTML**

```
<figure>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
  <figcaption>Title</figcaption>
</figure>
```

**CSS**

```
figure {
  padding:20px;
  display:block;
  background:#ffa2df;
  position: relative;
}

figure img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

figcaption {
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  text-align: center;
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column; 
  float:left; 
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately not, as the figure height is variable based on the width of the browser. I could fix the height as an option but I'd rather it were flexible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is possible using absolute positioning and having an inner rotated element also positioned absolutely.

Arguably this is also a kludge but the height is responsive although the text does not break..media queries would be required there.

```css
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
figure {
  padding: 20px;
  display: block;
  background: #ffa2df;
  position: relative;
}
figure img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
figcaption {
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 2em;
}
figcaption span {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding: 0 1em;
  line-height: 2em;
  transform-origin: top left;
  transform: translate(0%, 100%) rotate(-90deg);
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<figure>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
  <figcaption><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</span>
  </figcaption>
</figure>
```

Alternative: Experimental Property - [**Writing Mode @ MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/writing-mode)

> The writing-mode property defines whether lines of text are laid out horizontally or vertically and the direction in which blocks progress.

***This one is responsive.***

```css
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
figure {
  padding: 20px;
  display: block;
  background: #ffa2df;
  position: relative;
}
figure img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
figcaption {
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  padding: .5em;
  writing-mode: vertical-lr;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<figure>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
  <figcaption>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
  </figcaption>
</figure>
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a bit of a kludge, but this will work. Turn the figure into a table, keep the orientation of the figcaption and put a div inside that you rotate.

```css
figure {
  display:table;
  padding:20px;
  background:#ffa2df;
  direction:rtl;
}

figure img {
  display:table-cell;
  vertical-align:top;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

figcaption {
  display:table-cell;
  vertical-align:middle;
  width:20px; max-width:20px;
  background: red;
}

figcaption div {
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transform-origin: 25% 25%;
}
```

```html
<figure>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
  <figcaption><div>Title</div></figcaption>
</figure>
```

If a better answer comes along, I'll gladly delete this one!

Comment: Hello! Thanks so much for the answer! Works great, however I prefer not to use tables, hence marking the other answer as correct, thanks for your help!

Comment: OK. But can you explain why you prefer not to use display:table?

Comment: Just seems a little dated?

Comment: Thanks for the giggle.

Comment: Have up-voted your answer as it was very helpful, however I cannot accept 2 answers and so marked the answer that was best for me as correct. I don't think the sarcasm is helpful in this environment, where people are simply seeking some advice and guidance. Feel free to explain why your answer is a better solution.

Comment: I didn't say my answer was better, I just find it funny that people have such sentiments for certain CSS properties. So I didn't ask for you to justify your choice of answer.